# Align the element in line with the one below

Tags: css

how can i align the element in line with the one below over CSS i used margin left 456px but when i change the resolution of the screen the elemtn is on other place! Please look at the picture below!

How can i

```css
.LanguageSelector {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-left: 465px;   
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #f2f2f2 0%, white 51%); }
  .LanguageSelector span {
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 32px; }
    .LanguageSelector span a {
      font-weight: 600; }
```

[image]

Comment: Need HTML and an [example].

Comment: Please provide a working [repro] incl. your HTML as debugging details. Also, tag accordingly. You code indicates the usage of SASS/LESS

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to style the language selector, but you have to style the main element (div), whose children are the search box and the language selector.

Use display: flex; in your main element (div), whose children are the search box and the language selector. so all the elements, including search and language selector, will be in the same line.

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with `inline-block`. In any case it most likely is not a case that is caused by it in the first place.